How to redirect a user after a boolean check in Flutter
I have a button that checks the time difference, so I would want the user to be redirected if the button is active or when he clicks on the button when it is active. Below is what I have tried but I'm getting error, I will so much appreciate if anyone can help me out. below is what i have tried
 ElevatedButton( child: Text("Button2"), onPressed: \_isButtonActive ? \_handleButtonPress ? () { // to direct them to another page or API } : null),

Future<void> _handleButtonPress() async {
    try {
      await _firestore.collection('WithdrawalsAuthentications').doc(_uid).set({
        'date': Timestamp.now(),
      //    "uID": user.uid,
      //  "email":  user.email!,
       "amountRequested": _flexAmount,
      });
      setState(() {
        _isButtonActive = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error handling button press: $e");
    }
  }
    

but am gettting error "Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. Try changing the condition." above is my handleButton method

In your given code replace onPressed method with... onPressed: _isButtonActive ? (_handleButtonPress ? () {
// to direct them to another page or API
} : null) : null,

Thanks for your quick response, please I got this error on the (_handleButton "conditions must have a static type of bool, try changing the condition

Please share _handleButtonPress method for more clarification.

Future _handleButtonPress() async {
try {
await _firestore.collection('WithdrawalsAuthentications').doc(_uid).set({
'date': Timestamp.now(),
//    "uID": user.uid,
//  "email":  user.email!,
"amountRequested": _flexAmount,
});
  setState(() {
    _isButtonActive = false;
  });
} catch (e) {
  print("Error handling button press: $e");
}

}

the method gives me what i want, i only want to redirect the user when they click on the button when it is active it will redirect them to another page where they can make withdrawal

@samuelJen please add _handleButtonPress() method in your question. don't post code in the comment section.

i have added the handleButtonPress on my question

_handleButtonPress is a method and not a boolean value thats why its gives error "conditions must have a static type of bool, try changing the condition".
Try onPressed like... onPressed: _isButtonActive ? () async {
await _handleButtonPress();
} : null,

it worked, please how can i approve your answer.. thank you so much

I'm glad the solution worked for you!

Please how can I mark your answer as correct

Read documentation for vote or mark answer -
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269581/how-to-vote-on-comments

@DroidFlutter Please post your solution as an answer below, so that OP can upvote/accept it - and both the system and others can see that they've been helped.

I have added solution as an answer below.

_handleButtonPress not a boolean value thats why its gives error "conditions must have a static type of bool, try changing the condition"
Try onPressed method like below
 onPressed: _isButtonActive ? () async {
            await _handleButtonPress();
          } : null,

